# Vegan SIMPER analysis producing incorrect p values

Tags: r, p-value, vegan, dune

I have come across a bug in the updated SIMPER code. While running SIMPER on newer versions of R and RStudio, the resulting p-values for taxon with 0 observations is unreasonable.

For example, we have used the Dune data set, grouping by management. The focus will be on the contrast HF_NM.

As you can see in the results below, using an older version of R (3.6.0) Chenalbu and Cirsarve have zero observations, and therefore have a p value of 1.0.

Contrast: HF_NM

```
   Taxon    contr       sd contr.sd ava    avb        p   
Achimill 0.016555 0.014900   1.1111 1.2 0.3333 0.669323   
Agrostol 0.031915 0.028887   1.1048 1.4 2.1667 0.948207   
Airaprae 0.012605 0.018243   0.6910 0.0 0.8333 0.286853   
Alopgeni 0.024459 0.032399   0.7549 1.6 0.0000 0.940239   
Anthodor 0.028717 0.024799   1.1580 1.8 1.3333 0.286853   
Bellpere 0.008801 0.013732   0.6409 0.4 0.3333 0.916335   
Bromhord 0.012094 0.015169   0.7973 0.8 0.0000 0.836653   
Chenalbu 0.000000 0.000000      NaN 0.0 0.0000 1.000000   
Cirsarve 0.000000 0.000000      NaN 0.0 0.0000 1.000000   
Comapalu 0.010105 0.014556   0.6942 0.0 0.6667 0.215139   
Eleopalu 0.032043 0.032315   0.9916 0.8 2.1667 0.494024   
Elymrepe 0.029811 0.038676   0.7708 2.0 0.0000 0.458167   
Empenigr 0.004536 0.010325   0.4393 0.0 0.3333 0.581673   
Hyporadi 0.017141 0.026548   0.6457 0.0 1.1667 0.442231   
Juncarti 0.027414 0.028537   0.9607 1.6 1.1667 0.175299   
Juncbufo 0.018181 0.024648   0.7376 1.2 0.0000 0.386454   
Lolipere 0.054533 0.029625   1.8408 4.0 0.3333 0.151394   
Planlanc 0.041633 0.029560   1.4084 3.0 0.8333 0.007968  
Poaprat  0.041750 0.018852   2.2146 3.4 0.6667 0.015936  
Poatriv  0.071553 0.013681   5.2302 4.8 0.0000 0.019920  
Ranuflam 0.019285 0.019939   0.9672 0.4 1.3333 0.334661   
Rumeacet 0.046546 0.030806   1.5109 3.2 0.0000 0.003984  
Sagiproc 0.015282 0.016535   0.9243 0.8 0.5000 0.892430   
Salirepe 0.025340 0.027291   0.9285 0.0 1.8333 0.135458   
Scorautu 0.020703 0.014125   1.4658 2.8 3.1667 0.780876   
Trifprat 0.025843 0.025972   0.9951 1.8 0.0000 0.003984  
Trifrepe 0.030372 0.022871   1.3280 2.8 1.8333 0.617530   
Vicilath 0.002399 0.005461   0.4393 0.0 0.1667 0.836653   
Bracruta 0.035340 0.020104   1.7579 2.8 2.8333 0.290837   
Callcusp 0.016833 0.024901   0.6760 0.0 1.1667 0.438247
```

Whereas, in the results below, using a newer version of R (4.3.2) Chenalbu and Cirsarve have a p value of 0.4980 and 0.5976, respectively. Because there are 0 observations for both of these taxon, it is unreasonable to have a p value less than 0.9999.

Contrast: HF_NM

```
   Taxon average      sd   ratio     ava   avb      p   
Achimill 0.01656 0.01490 1.11100 1.20000 0.333 0.6534   
Agrostol 0.03192 0.02889 1.10500 1.40000 2.167 0.9442   
Airaprae 0.01261 0.01824 0.69100 0.00000 0.833 0.2829   
Alopgeni 0.02446 0.03240 0.75500 1.60000 0.000 0.9163   
Anthodor 0.02872 0.02480 1.15800 1.80000 1.333 0.2829   
Bellpere 0.00880 0.01373 0.64100 0.40000 0.333 0.9203   
Bromhord 0.01209 0.01517 0.79700 0.80000 0.000 0.8606   
Chenalbu 0.00000 0.00000     NaN 0.00000 0.000 0.4980   
Cirsarve 0.00000 0.00000     NaN 0.00000 0.000 0.5976   
Comapalu 0.01011 0.01456 0.69400 0.00000 0.667 0.2749   
Eleopalu 0.03204 0.03231 0.99200 0.80000 2.167 0.5538   
Elymrepe 0.02981 0.03868 0.77100 2.00000 0.000 0.4900   
Empenigr 0.00454 0.01033 0.43900 0.00000 0.333 0.5578   
Hyporadi 0.01714 0.02655 0.64600 0.00000 1.167 0.4263   
Juncarti 0.02741 0.02854 0.96100 1.60000 1.167 0.1912   
Juncbufo 0.01818 0.02465 0.73800 1.20000 0.000 0.3307   
Lolipere 0.05453 0.02962 1.84100 4.00000 0.333 0.1633   
Planlanc 0.04163 0.02956 1.40800 3.00000 0.833 0.0040  
Poaprat  0.04175 0.01885 2.21500 3.40000 0.667 0.0199   
Poatriv  0.07155 0.01368 5.23000 4.80000 0.000 0.0040  
Ranuflam 0.01928 0.01994 0.96700 0.40000 1.333 0.3586   
Rumeacet 0.04655 0.03081 1.51100 3.20000 0.000 0.0040  
Sagiproc 0.01528 0.01653 0.92400 0.80000 0.500 0.8566   
Salirepe 0.02534 0.02729 0.92900 0.00000 1.833 0.1155   
Scorautu 0.02070 0.01412 1.46600 2.80000 3.167 0.8526   
Trifprat 0.02584 0.02597 0.99500 1.80000 0.000 0.0040  
Trifrepe 0.03037 0.02287 1.32800 2.80000 1.833 0.6733   
Vicilath 0.00240 0.00546 0.43900 0.00000 0.167 0.8685   
Bracruta 0.03534 0.02010 1.75800 2.80000 2.833 0.3386   
Callcusp 0.01683 0.02490 0.67600 0.00000 1.167 0.4980
```

Does anyone know where the error may be arising and how to resolve it?
Because the taxon with 0 observations are incorrect, can I have confidence in the other resulting p values?

The SIMPER code produces the correct results when using an older ASUS running windows 10 (with R 3.6.0, Rstudio 1.3.1093, vegan 2.5-7, lattice 0.20-38, permute 0.9-5).

The SIMPER analysis produces unreasonable values when a use a Dell computer running Windows 10 pro (with R 4.3.2, vegan 2.6-4, lattice 0.21-9, permute 0.9-7). I have tried downloading older versions of R and Rstudio, as well as lattice, and it does not resolve the issue.

Below is the code I have used. Note: the suggested SIMPER code does not produce p values (only cumulative sum), thus, I have included an altered code which produces p values.

```
options(max.print=1000000)
options(scipen = 999)
library(vegan)

data(dune)
data(dune.env)

##As suggested Online -- Rdir.io https://rdrr.io/rforge/vegan/man/simper.html
(sim <- with(dune.env, simper(dune, Management)))
summary(sim)

##altered to output p value
dune2 <- with(dune.env, simper(dune, Management, permutations = 250))
summary(dune2, ordered = F)
```

I have tried un-installing and re-installing R and RStudio, using various versions of R and Rstudio, running different versions of Vegan, lattice, and permute, and using different computers. Only the Asus using an older version of R and RStudio produces reasonable results. I have tried using the same version of R and R studio on my Dell computer and cannot yield the same results.

Comment: It may help if you list the ASUS vs Dell package versions to allow others to test. You could also try 'cloning' R and its libraries from your ASUS machine onto your Dell to see if the issue persists. If there is a bug, you could get in touch will the [devs](https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan) to see if they know what is going on. Good luck!